# how to separate liferay web server and application server

Tags: web, liferay

I have a requirement to separate the liferay into web component in apache web server and service into apache tomcat. Could anyone provide me with some pointers on how to do the same?

thanks
L Raj

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please tell us more about what this should achieve - otherwise just pointing to mod_jk or mod_proxy might be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Apache cannot execute any jsp page or servlet, so you only could separate the static files (like images, css, js and so on) from the dynamic's (jsp, servlets, etc.).

So, as Olaf indicate in his comment we need more information about your objective or use the Apache features to make the split.

Best regards.